# Ошибка при обработке поле дата flask wtforms, sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Создал форму в которой есть поле дата с маской ввода imask.js
вводится 02.01.2020
при обработке формы выходит ошибка

> Incorrect date value: '12.11.1933'

В шаблоне

```
<form action="{{ url_for('dogovor09') }}" method="POST">
{{ form.dob(id='datepick_dob', class_="form-control mb-3", placeholder="Дата рождения") }}
        {% if form.dob.errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in form.dob.errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
</form>
```

во view

```
def dogovor09():
    form = DocForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit() and request.method == 'POST':
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        patronymic = request.form['patronymic']
        registration_adress = request.form['registration_adress']
        dob = request.form['dob']
        passport_number = request.form['passport_number']
        passport_date = request.form['passport_date']
        passport_given = request.form['passport_given']
        phone = request.form['phone']
        p_last_name = request.form['p_last_name']
        p_first_name = request.form['p_first_name']
        p_patronymic = request.form['p_patronymic']
        p_registration_adress = request.form['p_registration_adress']
        p_passport_number = request.form['p_passport_number']
        p_passport_date = request.form['p_passport_date']
        p_passport_given = request.form['p_passport_given']
        p_phone = request.form['p_phone']

        try:
            doc_user = Doc(last_name=last_name,
                           first_name=first_name,
                           patronymic=patronymic,
                           registration_adress=registration_adress,
                           dob=dob,
                           passport_number=passport_number,
                           passport_date=passport_date,
                           passport_given=passport_given,
                           phone=phone,
                           )
            db.session.add(doc_user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('success')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Ошибка:\n', traceback.format_exc())
            return redirect(url_for('fail'))

    title = 'Форма заявки'
    return render_template('dogovor09.html', form=form, title=title)
```

forms.py

```
class DocForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    patronymic = StringField('Patronymic')
    registration_adress = StringField('registration adress', validators=[DataRequired()])
    dob = DateField('DOB', validators=[DataRequired()], format='%d.%m.%Y')
    passport_number = IntegerField('passport number')
    passport_date = DateField('passport date', validators=[DataRequired()], format='%d.%m.%Y')
    passport_given = StringField('passport given')
    phone = IntegerField('phone', validators=[DataRequired()])
    p_first_name = StringField('Name')
    p_last_name = StringField('Last Name')
    p_patronymic = StringField('Patronymic')
    p_registration_adress = StringField('registration adress')
    p_passport_number = IntegerField('passport number')
    p_passport_date = DateField('passport date', validators=[DataRequired()], format='%d.%m.%Y')
    p_passport_given = StringField('passport given')
    p_phone = IntegerField('phone')
```

Почему то иногда работает валидация и указывает что формат даты не подходит, иногда не работает валидация.
Иногда проходит форма и данные добавляется. Не могу понять почему
как правильно обработать поле с датой чтобы добавить запись в бд?

в models
использую flask sqlalchemy mysql

```
class Doc(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # поля поступающего
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    patronymic = db.Column(db.String(100))
    registration_adress = db.Column(db.String(100))
    dob = db.Column(db.Date)
```

Comment: Покажите в каком формате у Вас записываются данные в БД.

Comment: использую flask sqlalchemy dob = db.Column(db.Date) mysql